# Anti-Siphon Sillcock Handle

Tags: plumbing, faucet, exterior

I just moved into a new home and the anti siphon sillcock on the outside of the house is leaking from behind the knob.  I tried to remove the handle via the center screw but it was rusted so badly it broke.  The handle still wont come off.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?  I assume I just need to replace the seal behind the handle...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it leaking at the stem or is it actually leaking at the vacuum breaker?  The breaker can allow a leak (or a gush) and the parts are replaceable (if you can find them - which you likely won't due to age).  A plumber would suggest replacement as that is the quicker fix and cheaper since time is money.

I'd replace that one with new and try to fix the old to be a replacement if needed later.  You'll be a step ahead next time.

Comment: Its leaking at the stem.  I am going to take your advice and just replace it

Answer (score 2):

The fastest solution will be to replace the whole thing. That is what a plumber will recommend.

Comment: Shouldn't the handle come off easily or is that not how these are supposed to work?

Comment: The handle should come off easily. The amount of corrosion probably indicates that you don't want that to happen as the next thing that will happen is that you break the stem, it's about 7-9 inches long as the valve is back in the other end. Get on the inside and check to see if the sillcock is threaded on, or soldered on. As this is also a frost proof device, there will be an 8-12 inch extension back to where it connects to the house plumbing. If it's threaded, remove the two screws on the escutcheon and use a pair of open end wrenches to remove the sillcock (after shutting off main valve).